# How do I save my keras model after every epoch?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, model, save, epoch

I have working image segmentation model that I am using. I have been adjusting the parameters of `model.fit()` to get the best results. It is currently running at about `1000 epochs`. I wanted to know if there is a way to include `model.save()` after every `nth` epoch instead just saving the model after the final epoch? I want to do this so that I can have a prediction that shows how the models accuracy increases and make a short animation that shows the image segmentation over time.

Comment: Look into creating a History object. See https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/callbacks/History?version=stable. You should also be able to find plenty of tutorials/example code to help set this up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved:

```
ModelCheckpoint('models\\unet_seg_{epoch:04d}.model', monitor=observe_var, save_best_only=False, period = 2)
```